# Color not coming through glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, glass

I'm trying to do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIUDZZMfGNI) tutorial to make the cup as shown in the video but I'm having problems with the glass and the color coming through it. 
[image: glass cup]
the glass has light coming through it (Or it might be just reflective) but the color of the coffee isn't coming through the glass and into the camera for some reason.

The nodes for the glass
[image: glass nodes]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: It may just be your angle of looking at the glass. There is a lot of white background colour that will impact (I dont know the correct terminology) on the colours you see through the glass?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Because I was having the exact same problem, and I mean *exact same*, I tried lowering my specularity to just .3 and here's the result. While the liquid looks amazing and I think the cup looks ok (too thin now, I'll have to scale the liquid down) there's a large reflection of the plate from the other side. How can I prevent the light reflecting off the plate from also going through the liquid? I would like for light to be diffused inside of the liquid.

[image]

I changed the lighting angle and it helped, haha. But there's still an odd reflection.